# ImageField attribute has no file associated with it

Tags: django

I have a model, which has 3 ImageField.  When loading a new entry into the database, it may have some blank images, so the value is None. When the client request the model data entry, I get in the server side:

> ValueError: The 'picture2' attribute has no file associated with it.

How can I avoid it?

```
class item (models.Model):

    certificate=models.ImageField(default=None) 
    provider = models.ForeignKey(serviceProvider, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True)
    radius = models.FloatField(default=None)
    description= models.TextField(blank = True)
    hour_init = models.TimeField()
    hour_end = models.TimeField()
    picture1=models.ImageField(default=None, blank=True)    
    picture2=models.ImageField(default=None,blank=True) 
    picture3=models.ImageField(default=None, blank=True)
```

This is the view function:

```
def addRubro (request):
    if request.method == 'POST': 
        if request.POST.get("tipo")=="2":
            proveedores=serviceProvider.objects.filter(user=request.POST.get("user"))
            if not proveedores:
                return HttpResponse("Bad")
            else:
                rubros=item.objects.filter(provider=proveedores.first())
                if len(rubros)<2:
                    new = item()
                    new.provider=proveedores.first()
                    new.radius=request.POST.get("radius")
                    new.description=request.POST.get("description")
                    new.hour_init=request.POST.get("hour_init")
                    new.hour_end=request.POST.get("hour_end") 
                    new.certificate=request.FILES.get("certificate")    
                    new.picture1=request.FILES.get("picture1")
                    new.picture2=request.FILES.get("picture2")
                    new.picture3=request.FILES.get("picture3")
                    new.save()  
                    return HttpResponse("Item loaded")
```

You can see that many times, a single image is sent, so the picture2 and picutre3 will be **None**.

Then when I try to send model information back to the client, I do it using this function

```
def requestRubros(request, tipo,user,rubro):
    if tipo=="2":
        proveedores=serviceProvider.objects.filter(user=user)
        if proveedores:
            rubro=item.objects.filter(provider=proveedores.first()).filter(items=rubro)
            if rubro:

                data = [{"radius": str(rubro.first().radius),
                "description": rubro.first().description,},
                
                {
                "hour_init": str(rubro.first().hour_init), "hour_end": str(rubro.first().hour_end)},
                
                {"certificate": "data:image/png;base64,"+base64.b64encode(rubro.first().certificate.read()).decode('ascii'),
                "picture1": "data:image/png;base64,"+(base64.b64encode(rubro.first().picture1.read())).decode('ascii'),
                "picture2": "data:image/png;base64,"+base64.b64encode(rubro.first().picture2.read()).decode('ascii'),
                "picture3": "data:image/png;base64,"+base64.b64encode(rubro.first().picture3.read()).decode('ascii')}]

                return JsonResponse(data, safe=False)

            else:
                return HttpResponse ("Bad data")
        else: 
            return HttpResponse ("Bad data")
```

If the ImageFields have blank=True atribute. Why it says The 'picture2' attribute has no file associated with it?

Comment: In your view `requestRubros` you call `picture2.read()`, etc. regardless whether there is a file or not giving you an error. Also it looks like you are making an API? Look into using [Django REST framework](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/) in that case.

Comment: Also those repeated calls to `rubro.first()` is absolutely inefficient. You are making repeated queries to the database each time you write that. Instead get the object **once** and use it.

Comment: @Abdul Aziz Barkat. How can I avoid using object.first()?

Comment: Store the result in a variable and use that `some_variable = rubro.first()`...

Comment: There is no way that the ImageField fields have a default data to be read? I thought you could with the black = True attribute

Comment: Can I sends the images without read it?